# New Azure WebJob Project - JobHostConfiguration/RunAndBlock missing after NuGet updates

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

Easy Replication

1. Create a new project 'ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework).
2. Build compile, update NuGet, all works.
3. Add: Add New Azure WebJob Project.
4. Build, compile. Happy
5. Update NuGet for the WebJob project.
6. Project no longer compiles.

Breaking changes were introduced
https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129

So I install

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage

This resolves QueueTriggerAttribute

But in program.cs

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();

        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

I am encountering the following problems:

1. JobHostConfiguration is now missing.
2. JobHost constructor now has two parameters, including a new IJobHostContextFactory?
3. RunAndBlock is missing.  It is now 'StartAsync'
4. The code now needs to become asynchronous since there are no synchronous calls to the job.

Questions:

1. What additioanl assemblies need to be installed?
2. What is this new JobHostContextFactory?
3. How do I configure the job now?
4. How should I update the code for asynchronous?
5. How do I block for a continuous job now that all we have is Start?

Thanks in advance!

- C#
- .Net Framework 4.6.2
- Visual Studio 2017 - v15.8.7

Comment: Here is a great example to get up and running with a simple .NET V3 WebJob with a  TimerTrigger: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264806/scheduled-net-webjob-v3-example?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 3.0.0 NuGet package update (non-beta) brought breaking changes. It's based on the generic host which is similar to the asp.net host. Here's an [example of the new setup](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/00686a5ae3b31ca1c70b477c1ca828e4aa754340/sample/SampleHost/Program.cs)

Here you can find a [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1870#issuecomment-417888043) related to that topic.

Comment: Here we go, down the rabbit hole. Thank you, btw.