# Warning: Only got partial types from assembly: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I've got a simple .NET V3 WebJob with a timer trigger up and running in a .NET website as outlined in this answer: [Scheduled .NET WebJob V3 example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264806/scheduled-net-webjob-v3-example/57266299#57266299)

However, in the output, I get this warning:

`` warn: Host.Startup[0]
      Warning: Only got partial types from assembly: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
      The following loader failures occured when trying to load the assembly:
         - Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
         - Method 'Commit' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.Bindings.DelegatingCloudBlobStream' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
         - Method 'Commit' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.Bindings.DelegatingCloudBlobStream' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
         - Method 'Commit' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.Bindings.DelegatingCloudBlobStream' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
         - Method 'Commit' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.Bindings.DelegatingCloudBlobStream' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
         - Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuerySegment' from assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
      This can occur if the assemblies listed above are missing, outdated or mismatched.
      Exception message: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
         at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
         at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.DefaultTypeLocator.FindTypes(Assembly assembly, IEnumerable`1 extensionAssemblies) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\DefaultTypeLocator.cs:line 115 ``

It's an open issue on GitHub (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2060). Does anyone have a fix?

More importantly, does it affect functionality in any way? The GitHub issue OP said no, but it would be good to have someone confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Install package ["Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage" Version="4.1.0"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage/4.1.0) to fix this error.

Also, to avoid any confusion, before I fixed this, the error message in the original question, due to package updates, had become the following:

```
warn: Host.Startup[0]
  Warning: Only got partial types from assembly: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
  The following loader failures occured when trying to load the assembly:
     - Method 'LogFunctionStarted' in type 'WebJobs.Host.Storage.Logging.PersistentQueueLogger' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
  This can occur if the assemblies listed above are missing, outdated or mismatched.
  Exception message: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
     at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
     at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.DefaultTypeLocator.FindTypes(Assembly assembly, IEnumerable`1 extensionAssemblies) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\DefaultTypeLocator.cs:line 115
```