# Azure WebJobs SDK TimerTrigger Functions not running

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am trying to Create an Azure WebJob that runs a function every x seconds. I am following the tutorials on the [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started) and this example of how to use TimerTrigger with WebJobs on [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions). However when I run locally my methods in Functions.cs do not seem to be running(no logging and break points aren't hit).

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder();
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            });
            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                await host.RunAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Functions.cs:

```
public class Functions
    {

        public static void TimerJob([TimerTrigger("00:00:03", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timer job fired!");
        }
    }
```

My only output in the debug console is:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Users\<blah>\<Project\bin\Debug\net472\
```

Here are my nuget packages and versions:

[image]

I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Could you please refer this https://energizedanalytics.com/en/azure-web-jobs-with-net-core/ & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to, it may help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I figured out why our timed trigger wasn't firing in our webjob. After installing the following `nuget packages,` I was able to get it to work using your `function.cs` code in my **.net framework 4.7.1** .

So To make our webjob with timer trigger  work, we'll need to use 2.X or 3.X versions with the following packages:

**Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions** -version 3.0.6

**Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage** -version 3.0.1

**Microsoft.Extensions.Logging** -version 2.1.0

**Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console** -version 2.1.0

For reference check all the packages which i used in my environment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" version="3.0.6" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage" version="3.0.14" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="ncrontab.signed" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.TraceSource" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow" version="4.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="9.3.1" targetFramework="net472" />
```

Here is my  **`Program.cs`** where i have added  `AddTimers` extension method just after  `b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();`

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
namespace usetimertrigger

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder();
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddTimers();
            });
            builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConsole();

            });
            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                host.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`function.cs`**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace usetimertrigger
{
    public class Functions
    {

        public static void TimerJob([TimerTrigger("00:00:03", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ajay timer trigger fired!");
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#create-an-azure-storage-account) ,  added my storage account access key which is copied from Azure portal>storage account>access key

[image]

And `appsettings.json` should be **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy always** for configure our storage connection string as shown below.

[image]

[image]

***Output***:-

**Before adding `b.AddTimers();`**

[image]

**After adding `b.AddTimers();`**

[image]

**Reference**:

SO THREAD : [Scheduled .NET WebJob V3 example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264806/scheduled-net-webjob-v3-example)